# RHEL 5 createrepo hangs

Tags: linux, rhel5, rpm

I've got a RHEL 5 server that I want to create a mirror repo on. I've specified a new file system mounted at `/repos`. I have run `reposync -p /repos --repoid=rhel-x86_64-server-5 -l` which completed OK.

I've then run `createrepo -c /repos/.createreop_cache /repos` which runs until around 17k items, then hangs. There are 20k items in total.

I can't find any logs to suggest what has happened, all I can see is that it is no longer processing anything…

Comment: I have not encountered this before but you shall try using strace and gdb to try and see what createrepo does while "hanging".

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when the /repo directory was on a NAS drive.
As a work around, I moved everything to /tmp which is mounted on locally installed disk. createrepo then ran fine. After I moved the /tmp/repo contents back to the NAS drive.